# Remainder when divided by 9

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'd like help with this question :

What is the remainder when

$$2^{2} + 22^{2} + 222^{2}+  \ldots + \underbrace{2222...22^{2}}_{49 \text{ times}} $$

is divided by  $9$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mod $9$, we have
$$2^2+22^2+\cdots+22\ldots 2^2$$
$$\equiv 2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+0^2+2^2+\cdots$$
$$\equiv 5(2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2+1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+0^2)+2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2$$
$$\equiv 5\cdot\frac{8\cdot 9\cdot 17}{6}+4+7+0+1\equiv 5\cdot 12\cdot 17+3\equiv 5\cdot 3\cdot (-1)+3\equiv 6$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $10^k\equiv 1\pmod{9}$, your sum is

$$ 4\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{49} k^2 = \left.\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}\right|_{n=49}=161700\equiv 1+6+1+7\equiv \color{red}{6}\pmod{9}.$$

Comment: Would you please explore in a bit details

Answer (score 0):

$22222=2222*10+2$, then with out the squares, modulo $9$, you have the sequence
$$2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,0,2,4...,$$
Then with the squares you have the sequence
$$4,7,0,1,1,0,7,0,4,7,...$$
Can you take it from here?